# Do previous intraday/s data get automatically merged to the main table?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

So I am new with Firebase and also new to linking Firebase data to BigQuery (I have some BigQuery experience though).

According to the documentation:

"After you link a project to BigQuery, the first daily export of events creates a corresponding dataset in the associated BigQuery project. Then, each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new daily table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time."

Let's say I have this dataset `mydataset.myapp`, the corresponding BigQuery tables containing streamed data from Firebase looks like this:

```
mydataset.myapp.events_
mydataset.myapp.events_intraday_20191227
```

My question is: 
Are the previous intradays (`events_intraday_20191227`) automatically merged/appended to the main table (`events_`) by the next day? So `myapp` will not be populated with `intraday_<date>` crumbs of data ? Just want to confirm how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table events_ contains all your data for different dates, the table events_intraday_ is a temporary table, which its data is moved into events_

In [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ki_F6VCOtXU) you can find a video that explains how it works